# CREATE_FAILED ; <name> ; AWS::AppSync::Resolver ; The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey;

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm trying to run `amplify push` after creating a resolver. The initial error is:

- CREATE_FAILED ; BatchAddTodosResolver ; AWS::AppSync::Resolver ;  The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey;

This is followed by these errors:

- UPDATE_FAILED ; CustomResourcesjson ; AWS::CloudFormation::Stack ; Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-2::stack/amplify--dev-153155--1BXI79QFMXX10-CustomResourcesjson-8BPZCI05LJ2U/cdd9bb90-1729-11ed-8fd7-06e957346298 was not successfully updated. Currently in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS with reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [BatchAddTodosResolver].
- UPDATE_FAILED ; CustomResourcesjson ; AWS::CloudFormation::Stack

I've done the following (following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@jan.hesters/creating-graphql-batch-operations-for-aws-amplify-with-appsync-and-cognito-ecee6938e8ee)):

- Create Amplify app with `amplify init` and `amplify add api`; `amplify add auth`;
- Create mutation in `schema.graphql`:

```
input CreateTodoInput {
  id: ID
  title: String!
  description: String
  completed: Boolean
}

type Mutation {
  batchAddTodos(todos: [CreateTodoInput]): [Todo]
}
```

- `amplify update api`
- Add [this code](https://medium.com/@jan.hesters/creating-graphql-batch-operations-for-aws-amplify-with-appsync-and-cognito-ecee6938e8ee#file-customresources-json-LC1) to `amplify/api/<your-api-name>/stacks/CustomResources.json`
- Create `amplify/backend/api/<your-api-name>/resolvers/Mutation.batchAddTodos.req.vtl` (as per [the example](https://medium.com/@jan.hesters/creating-graphql-batch-operations-for-aws-amplify-with-appsync-and-cognito-ecee6938e8ee#file-mutation-batchaddtodos-req-vtl-LC1) and `amplify/backend/api/<your-api-name>/resolvers/Mutation.batchAddTodos.res.vtl` (as per the example below the req.vtl example)
- Update the references to the DynamoDB table in the `req.vtl`
- `amplify push`

There was an item in the instructions that I could not follow:

> Note: You need to run amplify add api without the batchAddTodos mutation first and then add it via amplify update api.

I assumed that `amplify update api` was wrong, since we'd already set up the API and the article provided no further instructions to indicate why we would want to run `amplify update api`. I think the author meant that the we would add the changes by running `amplify push` - but perhaps this is where I've gone wrong and am getting the

Answer (score 1):

I've got this working. I tried repeating the steps and noticed that if I don't update the `schema.graphql` correctly then the error above results. Perhaps I had not named the mutation correctly, or possibly forgotten to save my `schema.graphql` file before running `amplify push`?